# How to import code style scheme on Intellij from outside the IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style, formatter

If I want to add a global scheme to my Java code style I need to go to:

1. Settings -> Code Style -> Java
2. I click into the engine Icon -> Import Scheme
3. And I select some XML with the code style that I want to use

My idea is to automate this process, by creating some playbook where I install intellij and programmatically add the formatter to the fresh installation.

I found some stuff related to applying the format by running the command "idea format", but that's not what I want. I want to set the code style globally as I usually do by following the 3 step I've described previously.

Comment: I ignore whether this is helps you, but IDE code style and other configurations are located in filesystem (tried on Ubuntu) under `~/.IntelliJIdea2019.3/config/`.
You can most likely replace the `Default.xml` code style in there.

Comment: That's exactly what I've wanted. I was trying to search that into the installation folder :facepalm:. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for IDE global settings under Ubuntu led me to `~/.IntelliJIdea2019.3/config/` folder.
It contains various IDE files, among which `codestyles` and `jba_config/codestyles` (according to [Advanced configuration - Help | IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#system-directory), the latter exists if you are using [IDE settings sync](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#IDE_settings_sync)).

You should then be able to simply replace the `Default.xml` configuration directly from within file system.